# sybase : get list of stored procs used by a stored proc

Tags: dependencies, sybase

is there a way to determine the list of stored procs used by a specific stored proc.

Eg : SP A does exec SP B

when i tried sp_depends A, some how it doesn't seem to list out the SP B that SP A execs.

Answer (score 1):

`sp_depends` is the only way. It should show that B is executed by A. However, `sp_depends` will not show

1. executed stored procedures located in other databases than the current one
2. stored procedures executed as a variable (i.e. `EXECUTE @procname`) or
3. stored procedures executed via execute-immediate `EXECUTE('exec myproc')`